# How do I center an image horizontally in a div when it may be larger or smaller?

Tags: html, css

I have a div of a fixed width (or, rather, a fixed percentage width) and I want to include an centered image inside it.

The image is of a fixed height, but sometimes it will be narrower than the div and other times wider. In the case of images which are wider I am cropping them using `overflow:hidden`.

In both cases I want the image centered horizontally. My problem is that I can do it for each case, but haven't been able to come across a solution which applies to both.

For the image which is smaller than the div I can use `margin:0 auto;` or `text-align:center`, and for the larger images I can use `position:relative;left:-25%;`.

I suppose what I am looking for is a way to define a position relative to the center instead of the left or right hand side. Does such a thing exist? Or are there any other workarounds?

Comment: Why would the image be larger that the parent div? Oh, and there is no such property as `float:center`

Comment: I'm using images of different proportions, and fixing the height. I don't want them to exceed a certain width, so I want to crop the excess on each side.

As for `float:center`, sorry that's my mistake. I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require IE8 support, you can do:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: Thanks. IE8 support isn't critical, so I'll give this a go. However, it would be nice to work on IE8 if possible - do you know of any equivalent way it could be done?

Comment: If you know the width of the element, you could use margin-left: -(element width / 2)px

Answer (score 1):

css image:

```
position:relative;
left:50%;
margin-left: -**yourimageWidth/2**px; (ed: -150px for image with 300px)
```

Comment: I tried using text-align but while it centers the smaller images, it doesn't work on those with overflow - it still crops from only one side. (That's actually what I meant to write instead of `float:center` - I will edit it to save confusion.

Comment: Yes I didn't read the problem with the larger image, look up and try this

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I'd like to have a solution that applies to images of all widths rather than having to fix it manually for each. But if it comes down to it, this looks like a good solution.

Comment: for an automatic solution use jQuery
`$(".center").each(function(){
 $(this).css("marginLeft": -($(this).width()/2)+"px")
})`